# what is lsof showing?

Tags: linux, lsof

this is the output when i do

> lsof -p pid

while my programme is running.

```
scos-main 60367 root 754u REG 253,0 486 8653830 /apps/const/pkg/pkgout/.its-traceError.log
    scos-main 60367 root 758u REG 253,0 486 8653830 /apps/const/pkg/pkgout/.its-traceError.log
    scos-main 60367 root 761u REG 253,0 486 8653830 /apps/const/pkg/pkgout/.its-traceError.log
    scos-main 60367 root 762u REG 253,0 486 8653830 /apps/const/pkg/pkgout/.its-traceError.log
    scos-main 60367 root 766u REG 253,0 486 8653830 /apps/const/pkg/pkgout/.its-traceError.log
    scos-main 60367 root 767u REG 253,0 486 8653830 /apps/const/pkg/pkgout/.its-traceError.log
```

If You see this output there are so many references for the file .its-traceError.log. but the inode no of the file is the same.

What does that mean?
is it an issue or any fd leak?

OR

Does it imply that i have opened this file multiple times?

Comment: `wc -l` should show you the count of open files. The output here seems incorrect to me.

Comment: Also the `-p` parameter expects a pid include/exclude expression

Comment: @theTuxRacer edited the question. it is list of open files

Answer (score 3):

The fourth column shows the file descriptor numbers which are all different. That means your process has opened the file multiple times.